# Constrained least-squares using Python

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, linear-algebra, least-squares

I'm trying to do a least-squares fitting using Python/Scipy with some constraints such that all of the coefficients are in the range (0,1) and their sum is less or equal to 1.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to tackle this problem?

This is what I have tried to do:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def fmin(x,A,b):
    y = np.dot(A, x) - b
    return np.dot(y, y)

A = np.array(
[[8.00901083e-03, 6.00592597e-03, 2.88275795e-03, 1.43159580e-03,
  7.22346553e-04, 3.80569910e-04],
 [6.00592597e-03, 4.80578475e-03, 2.37175308e-03, 1.17547202e-03,
  6.02063819e-04, 3.23039326e-04],
 [2.88275795e-03, 2.37175308e-03, 1.32021653e-03, 6.88251743e-04,
  3.70218608e-04, 2.13992623e-04],
 [1.43159580e-03, 1.17547202e-03, 6.88251743e-04, 4.00016878e-04,
  2.35134567e-04, 1.46587630e-04],
 [7.22346553e-04, 6.02063819e-04, 3.70218608e-04, 2.35134567e-04,
  1.58475329e-04, 1.08484079e-04],
 [3.80569910e-04, 3.23039326e-04, 2.13992623e-04, 1.46587630e-04,
  1.08484079e-04, 8.33150747e-05]])


b = [0.00497762, 0.00391093, 0.00197284, 0.00100026, 0.0005192,  0.0002871 ]

args = (A,b)

bnds = ((0, None), (0, None),(0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None))
res = optimize.minimize(fmin, [0.11, 0.13, 0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17],args, method='SLSQP',
bounds=bnds,constraints=cons,tol=1e-10,options={'disp': False})

print ("\n res\n", res)
```

I noticed two issues in my code:

1) the sum of coefficients always adds to 1,

2) a solution depends on initial guess. It works like a random generator.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I noticed:

1. Your bounds are (0,None), but you specifically said you wanted your coefficients to be between 0 and 1, so I would change that to (0,1).
2. We can't see your constraints (you reference them in your optimize.minimize call) but they aren't defined in the code you put up. Are your constraints properly defined?

I ran your code (with the aforementioned adjustments) and it seemed to work for me:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def fmin(x,A,b):
    y = np.dot(A, x) - b
    return np.dot(y, y)

A = np.array(
[[8.00901083e-03, 6.00592597e-03, 2.88275795e-03, 1.43159580e-03,
  7.22346553e-04, 3.80569910e-04],
 [6.00592597e-03, 4.80578475e-03, 2.37175308e-03, 1.17547202e-03,
  6.02063819e-04, 3.23039326e-04],
 [2.88275795e-03, 2.37175308e-03, 1.32021653e-03, 6.88251743e-04,
  3.70218608e-04, 2.13992623e-04],
 [1.43159580e-03, 1.17547202e-03, 6.88251743e-04, 4.00016878e-04,
  2.35134567e-04, 1.46587630e-04],
 [7.22346553e-04, 6.02063819e-04, 3.70218608e-04, 2.35134567e-04,
  1.58475329e-04, 1.08484079e-04],
 [3.80569910e-04, 3.23039326e-04, 2.13992623e-04, 1.46587630e-04,
  1.08484079e-04, 8.33150747e-05]])


b = [0.00497762, 0.00391093, 0.00197284, 0.00100026, 0.0005192,  0.0002871 ]

args = (A,b)

bnds = ((0, 1), (0, 1),(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 1.0-np.sum(x) })
res = optimize.minimize(fmin, [0.11, 0.5, 0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17],args, method='SLSQP',
bounds=bnds,constraints=cons,tol=1e-10,options={'disp': False})

print ("\n res\n", res)
print("Sum of coefficients {}".format(np.sum(res.x)))
print("Difference vector:\n{}".format(np.dot(A,res.x) - b))
```

The results:

```
 res
      fun: 1.01628082156861e-09
     jac: array([-9.22056775e-09, -1.17219215e-08, -1.75126229e-08, -1.36469735e-08,
       -9.97111414e-09, -7.49388410e-09])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 72
     nit: 9
    njev: 9
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.17233894, 0.52326708, 0.09570958, 0.07287169, 0.06681423,
       0.06899848])
Sum of coefficients 0.9999999999999999
Difference vector:
[ 9.98723723e-08  1.40076137e-05 -1.89557823e-05 -1.76076427e-05
 -9.02962303e-06 -8.31701569e-06]
```

The result is quite good and the constraints are met, are you sure there's a problem...?